# How to run a java executable in jar

Tags: java

I have developed my "hello wold" java program and packaged it in a .jar file, but I have failed to run it as an executable software on a computer.

Comment: You need to use google more. This is not an unique question

Comment: Google -> "run a java .jar" or "run a java executable", top 10 hits.

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us what errors you are receiving and what you have tried? It might make it easier to answer if we knew what the situation was. Remember when you post questions, we might not know everything you know about the problem, so be as descriptive as you can, include examples, error messages, snippets of code etc. if you can. Also, things like the operating system might also be relevant. Please take the time to give us as much information as you can, then someone will take the time to give you a suitable answer.

Comment: Instead of exporting to a .jar, select Runnable Jar from the list. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate a "runnable JAR" using your IDE for example. If you're using Eclipse, do "right clic on your project > Export... > Java > Runnable JAR file". Once you got your JAR file, run it with the command `java -jar myRunnableJarFile.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

you need a MANIFEST.MF file within a folder named META-INF. Write the following into the MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: your.package.HelloWorld
```

Package this folder/file with your compiled class files. Then open a terminal (or type "cmd" into Start/Execute for Windows OS) and write the following to start your application:

```
java -jar yourapp.jar
```

Then it should work as long you have Java RE on your system classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with a command line? If so, navigate to the folder your jar is in and type this:

java -jar filename.jar